# unity / blender / FBX / semi transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

Im getting a strange issue with importing .FBX into unity. It does not look like it's an issue with normals. I have noticed on unity the material is classed as 'transparent' and changing this to 'opaque' does fix the issue but i would like to find out whats going on here.

Unity: 2018.3.3f1

Blender: 2.80.0

[image: Blender]
[image: Unity]
[image: Blender normals]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just run into a similar issue. I've not figured out why it's happening yet, but there seems to be [a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T59850) out. Will update if I find out what's causing it.

### Update 2020-02-13:

As [Cristopher Kawell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480605/2123178) mentions, this does indeed seem to have been fixed in the most recent (post-2.81?) versions of Blender - thanks Chris for pointing this out!

### Update 2019-02-13:

Haven't found the exact underlying cause but I've had a few minutes to test out a few things. It seems like blender is using the base colour's R channel as both the Red colour *and* an inverse Alpha channel value if the R value is anything other than 1.0 or 0, ignoring the Alpha channel completely, and keeping G and B channels as the values they should be.

#### Some examples:

All of the below assume a basic model (a cube, say), and no modifications to anything other than the Base Color property of the singular material applied to that model.

- `RGBA(1,1,1,1)` in blender, Opaque `RGBA(1,1,1,1)` in Unity
- `RGBA(1,1,1,0)` in blender, Opaque `RGBA(1,1,1,1)` in Unity
- `RGBA(0.9,1,1,1)` in blender, Transparent `RGBA(0.9,1,1,0.1)` in Unity
- `RGBA(0.1,1,1,1)` in blender, Transparent `RGBA(0.1,1,1,0.9)` in Unity
- `RGBA(0.1,0,0.1,1)` in blender, Transparent `RGBA(0.1,0,0.1,0.9)` in Unity
- `RGBA(0,1,1,1)` in blender, Opaque `RGBA(0,1,1,1)` in Unity

So, to reiterate:

- changing Alpha has no effect on transparency for imported models.
- R values of 0 or 1 equate to an Alpha value of 1
- R values between 0 and 1 equate to an Alpha value of `1 - R`
- B and G values do not affect transparency

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issue has been resolved by blender: https://developer.blender.org/T59850

If anyone is still having issues, try updating to the latest of Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply texture to a model, make sure the base color is set to white (r - 1.0, g - 1.0, b - 1.0, A - 1.0), for some reason when you apply texture to a model, it will appear good in blender, but unity will take basic color of the model and apply the texture on top of it.

I tested this with having file extensions for 2.8 [replaced blender installation folder with 2.8 beta files] and by saving .blend file in my unity project, i had to click on model viewer to update materials but they appeared properly in the end.