# Blender 2.8 model materials appear semi transparent when imported to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm using Blender 2.8 and when a model exported as FBX and imported to unity materials appear semi transparent (even blender default material). When material is selected in unity it shows render mode as transparent and can't edit it.Please help.

[Model in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcvjM.png)

[Blender material in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGy0s.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. The work-around that I'm using is clicking on the imported fbx in the project tab in Unity, going to the Materials tab in the Inspector, then "Extract Materials...". The extracted materials can then be edited and will auto-apply to the game object. Hope someone knows a better solution though.

UPDATE:
It appears blender has fixed this issue: https://developer.blender.org/T59850

Answer (score -1):

there is an issue on for blender on this: https://developer.blender.org/T59850

also there is this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54462858/2139679